# How to use Jenkins to build github project inside docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to trigger a build of the github project every time Jenkins receives a push of commits from github, then build the project inside docker container using the docker image I specified.

Currently, I have the Jenkinsfile like following:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'docker-image' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "source build/envsetup.sh"
                sh "lunch astar_parrot-tina"
                sh "make -j"
                sh "pack -d"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And following error:

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /root/.jenkins/workspace/tina-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[tina-pipeline] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . docker-image
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 -w /root/.jenkins/workspace/tina-pipeline -v /root/.jenkins/workspace/tina-pipeline:/root/.jenkins/workspace/tina-pipeline:rw,z -v /root/.jenkins/workspace/tina-pipeline@tmp:/root/.jenkins/workspace/tina-pipeline@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** zequanhannto/tina cat
$ docker top 459169f2aea2499f4c361291733308fafa74ec63e08b7a1b74814e0bb9077d51 -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
[tina-pipeline] Running shell script
+ source build/envsetup.sh
/root/.jenkins/workspace/tina-pipeline@tmp/durable-386f0363/script.sh: 2: /root/.jenkins/workspace/tina-pipeline@tmp/durable-386f0363/script.sh: source: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 459169f2aea2499f4c361291733308fafa74ec63e08b7a1b74814e0bb9077d51
$ docker rm -f 459169f2aea2499f4c361291733308fafa74ec63e08b7a1b74814e0bb9077d51
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

I don't understand why does Jenkins not run the steps inside the docker container. I was thinking all the steps will be executed inside the docker container. How can I let Jenkins run all the steps inside the docker container? And will all the code of the github project be copied into the docker container before the steps be executed?